# how can i find second maximum of my query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my SQL query to find a row in `currency_price` table grouped by maximum date of inserting to table. My question is how to find the **second maximum**. I mean how can I change this query to find the *second maximum row in each group*:

```
select currency_id,buy,sell 
from (select * from currency_price  order by `currency_id`, cu_date desc,buy,sell) x 
group by `currency_id`
```

with this query i found a row for each id so for example i have sell and buy for each id .exm:

```
id    sell buy
1000  500  480
1001  20   19
...
```

but here i want the second maximum date for each id.

I know some query to find second maximum but all does not take me to my answer.

Comment: im using mysql and use the query in php 5.5

Comment: can you give a full minimal table and the resultset of what you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

If it is MySql then Use `LIMIT 1,1`;  # Retrieve rows [start with rec]1-[fetch rec count]1

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: This is just a example ..adjust 1,1 to your requirement

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you set LIMIT 5,1 then it will fetch 6th record, if you set LIMIT 5,2 then it will fetch 6th and 7th record and so on...if it is LIMIT 0,10 it will fetch 10 records starting from the first record. NOTE Counter starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

**Sample**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AGE DESC) RNUM  FROM TEST_TABLE
) QUERY1 WHERE RNUM=2
```

Comment: Mysql doesnt have row_number

Comment: can you explane more?

Comment: Sorry, as Tim rightly points out - this isn't relevant to your situation. My solution is for SQL Server not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add a group order number to your initial ordered query & then select the second from each row.

The inner query, orders as required & numbers the rows starting from 1, resetting each time the currency_id changes.

```
set @num := 0, @ci := -1;

select currency_id,buy,sell 
from
  (select *,
    @num := if(@ci = currency_id, @num + 1, 1) as gp_number,
    @ci := currency_id as dummy 
  from currency_price
  order by `currency_id`, cu_date desc,buy,sell) x
where gp_number=2
```

This could be put into a stored procedure from workbench as follows :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SecondMaximum()
BEGIN
set @num := 0, @ci := -1;

select currency_id,buy,sell 
from
  (select *,
    @num := if(@ci = currency_id, @num + 1, 1) as gp_number,
    @ci := currency_id as dummy 
  from currency_price
  order by `currency_id`, cu_date desc,buy,sell) x
where gp_number=2;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And from PHP you execute "CALL SecondMaximum();"

If you wanted to be able to change tables and/or fields, then you could pass these as string variables to the procedure & create & execute a prepared statement within the stored procedure. Just do a google search for tutorials on those.

Comment: how can i use it in php?

Comment: thank u the query is write but i cant use it in my php code.it just work in phpmyadmin or workbench

Comment: You could create a stored procedure & then call that.

Comment: can u explane more?

Comment: I have added more to the answer. Another alternative may be to use the mysqli multi_query function with the original code - you would have to skip over the first result set for the "set @num ..." line. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: phpmyadmin of my host said : #1044 - Access denied for user 'gigfa_18516878'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'gigfa_18516878_ex1'. when i want to create a stored procedure.what should i do?

Comment: That sound like you do not have the permissions set to be able to create stored procedures - you will need to get your database administrator to give you those privileges. If you have sufficient privilege, you may be able to this yourself through Workbench under "Users & Privileges" on the Management tab. If you cannot get the privileges, then I suggest you look at the mysqli multi_query command I mentioned in my last comment which ought to allow you to run the original code.

Comment: i read somwhere about mysqli_multi_query but does not work for me. do you know how can i use it?

Comment: I did give you a link to the manual - try looking at the example & seeing if you can get something to work, if it fails then asking another question about why that fails, with details about what you have tried and what happens, would be the way to go.